# How can i import CA certificates to my Linux server(Archlinux)?

Tags: linux, certificate-authority

i can only connect my server by ssh,none web browser and other GUI tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the certificates in apache web server, then you need to configure in the SSL Virtualhost the [SSLCertificateChainFile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) option.

Comment: And if you want them imported into Postfix, Cyrus, Dovecot, whatever, you have to follow the instructions given in the manual.